# How to run scripted editor on Windows 7

Tags: javascript, windows-7, batch-file, editor

I am trying to run scripted editor on Windows XP and get **could not connect to localhost:7261**. There is same question [here](https://github.com/scripted-editor/scripted/wiki/FAQ) in Troubleshooting section. Suggestion is to delay running scripted for node to start. I delayed it with following batch script in bin/scripted.bat

```
start /MIN cmd /c node %rootdir%\server\scripted.js^>^>scripted.log
timeout /t 30
start "" "http://localhost:7261/editor.html?%patharg%"
```

I get the same error **could not connect to localhost:7261**.

How to configure scripted to run after node complete running?

I use scripted version 0.2.0 and node version 0.8.0-x86.

Comment: The [exact same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13130515/how-to-run-scripted-editor-on-windows-7) was already closed. Please consider rewording it  and perhaps adding more details to it so that it can be properly answered.

Comment: Send a message to the scripted mailing list over here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/scripted-dev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often times the browser starts before the node server is running - just wait a second and press refresh.

If that fails, you'll find node isn't running. So you either don't have nodeJS installed, it's not on your `PATH` or it's not a new enough version.

Also, check scripted.log in the same folder as you ran `scr` from.